# Body Shadow Css

Tags: html, css

I want to add outer shadow to my page body, for example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Shadow</title>
    <style>
      html{height:100%;}
      body{height:100%;}
      #shadow{width:1200px;background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3fOE.png');height:100%;margin: 0 auto;}
      #theMainContainer{width:900px;margin:0 auto;background-color:red;height:100%;text-align:center; color:white;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="shadow">
      <div id="theMainContainer">
        i have <font color="black">shadow</font> in the left side and the right side of the page ,<br>But i have space in the top and in the bottom of the page(what is the best way to fix it?).
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have space in the top and in the bottom of the page. How can I remove the space and make the shadow to a 100% height?

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin: 0` to body:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: also add padding: 0 to the body tag

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following css rule to reset the browser's default styling.

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```